gnuplot and gnuplottex issue version of Overleaf
I'm using the subscribed version of Overleaf with pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.7.16). I'm having trouble with gnuplot and gnuplottex when trying to compile my LaTeX document. The same code works fine in the non-subscribed version of Overleaf, which uses pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.3.29), but it fails in the subscribed version.
Here's the code I'm using tikzpicture environment that uses gnuplot
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
 \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{120}, % Top-down view
        colormap/viridis, % Color map
        colorbar,
        colorbar style={title=Value},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        title={Level curve plot of the function},
    ]
        \addplot3[
            contour gnuplot={
                % levels=={10,1000},
                % labels=true,
                  labels= false,
            },
            samples=25,
            domain=-100:100,
            y domain=-100:100
        ]
        { sin(1.3*x)*cos(0.9*y) + (cos(0.8*x)*sin(1.9*y))^2 + cos(0.2*x*y)^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

The error messages I'm getting are
Package pgfplots Error: sorry, plot file{output_contourtmp0.table} could not be opened.
I've tried several solutions, including checking the -shell-escape option and the system's PATH, but nothing seems to work.
In addition, I have a
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage} % just to make all the plots fit on a page

\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\title{Using gnuplottex on Overleaf}
\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf,terminaloptions={font ",10" linewidth 3}]
    plot sin(x), cos(x)
\end{gnuplot}

\begin{gnuplot}[scale=0.8]
    set grid
    set title 'gnuplottex test $e^x$'
    set ylabel '$y$'
    set xlabel '$x$'
    plot exp(x) with linespoints
\end{gnuplot}

\gnuplotloadfile[terminal=pdf]{example.gnuplot}

\end{document}

And the example.gnuplot file contains: plot cos(x)
This code also works fine in the non-subscribed version of Overleaf but fails in the subscribed version
The error messages I'm getting are related to gnuplot and gnuplottex not being found or executed correctly.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?
Thank you in advance for your help!

I noticed in a comment you said the subscribed overleaf is actually the 'shared overleaf of some university' and possibly/probably hosted on a different server. I think this may be highly relevant, though it is hard to be sure without more details. but I know in some cases installations are incomplete or misconfigured and some things may fail. moreover, the way to get these problems resolved is then different because overleaf doesn't necessarily have any control over the setup.

I concur with your point. The university-shared Overleaf version could be relevant to the issue. It’s possible that some installations might be incomplete or misconfigured. Resolving these issues might require a different approach, as Overleaf may not control the setup. I’ve contacted the responsible individuals at the university about this issue. This is a crucial step towards a solution. Thanks for your insightful comment.
